# tikz circuits: How to change color of resistor "adjustable" arrow?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, circuits

I am trying to change the color of the arrow that is added to a resistor to indicate that it is adjustable.  I can only seem to change the color of the resistor symbol, the wire to/from the resistor, and the symbol, but not the adjustable arrow.  Here is my minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick, circuit ee IEC, set resistor graphic=var resistor IEC graphic]
  \draw [red] (0.0, 0.0) to [resistor={blue, adjustable, info'={$R$}}] (3.0, 0.0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which produces this image:

[image: Colored resistor]

I have tried `adjustable=blue` and `adjustable={color=blue}`, but neither work.  Any ideas?

Comment: `adjustable={every edge/.append style=blue}` works but I expected `adjustable=blue` to work too but alas …

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Oh, you beat me! This is of course a bit simpler even than my approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option `adjustable` adds an annotation to the node. You can color such an annotation, using the option `annotation arrow/.append style={every edge/.append style={blue}}`. So, you could do:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    very thick, 
    circuit ee IEC, 
    set resistor graphic=var resistor IEC graphic,
    annotation arrow/.append style={every edge/.append style={blue}},
]
  \draw[red] (0.0, 0.0) to[resistor={blue, adjustable, info'={$R$}}] (3.0, 0.0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If you only want to color specific arrows, you can also append this option to the `to` path that has the `resistor` option, such as:

```
\draw[red] (0.0, 0.0) to[annotation arrow/.append style={every edge/.append style={blue}}, resistor={blue, adjustable, info'={$R$}}] (3.0, 0.0);
```

As @Qrrbrbirlbel pointed out in the comments, you can even just write:

```
\draw[red] (0.0, 0.0) to[resistor={blue, adjustable={every edge/.append style={blue}}, info'={$R$}}] (3.0, 0.0);
```

[image]

---

Why is that? If you look up the code for the annotations, you will find that annotations in general are declared as follows:

```
\tikzset{
  circuit declare annotation/.style args={#1#2#3}{%
    #1/.style={
      append after command={%
        \bgroup
          [current point is local=true]
          [every circuit annotation/.try]
          [every #1/.try]
          [shift={(\tikzlastnode.north)}]
          [annotation arrow,->]
          [label distance=#2,##1]
          #3
          \tikz@after@path%
        \egroup%
      }
    }
  },
  annotation arrow/.style = {
    /utils/exec={\pgfsetarrowoptions{direction ee}{.4*\the\tikzcircuitssizeunit+.3*\the\pgflinewidth}},
    >=direction ee,
  }
}%
```

And a specific annotation definition contains essentially only the path declaration, such as:

```
\tikzset{circuit declare annotation={adjustable}{1.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit}
  {
    [shift=(\tikzlastnode.center)]
    (-1.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit,-1.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit) edge[line to] (1.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit,1.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit)
  }
}%
```

In order to color this path, say, blue, we need to add the option `blue` to the edge of the path declaration, which we can do using `every edge/.append style={blue}`.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response.  I appreciate that you not only provided code that works but that you took the time to explain the answer.

Answer (score 3):

To break it down:

```
\tikz\path {[blue] (0,0) edge[line to] (1,1) };
```

does not draw a blue line and that's what's happening here:
Any option you give to the annotations, e.g. `adjustable = blue` is placed in front of the actual edge that makes up the path of that arrow.

(The resistor itself is a node and nodes also don't pass their options to annotations which are placed on the path after the node.)

We could patch the annotations defining style `declare circuits annotation` but that would need you to load `circuits` and `circuits.ee.IEC` in separate steps.

Here I'll just define uppercase variants of the annotations that forward their value to the `every edge` style inside the annotations.

---

Of course, if you want all your annotations blue you better do

```
annotation arrow/.append style={every edge/.append style=blue}
```

or if you want just the adjustables blue:

```
every adjustable/.append style={every edge/.append style=blue}
```

Maybe you want all adjustable resistors blue:

```
adj resistor/.style={resistor={blue,#1,adjustable={every edge/.append style=blue}}},
adj resistor'/.style={resistor={blue,#1,adjustable'={every edge/.append style=blue}}},
adj resistor/.default=,
adj resistor'/.default=,
```

which you can then use with `to[adjresistor]`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\tikzset{
  /utils/tempa/.style={
    \MakeUppercase #1/.style={#1={every edge/.append style={##1}}},
    \MakeUppercase #1/.default=},
  /utils/tempa/.list={adjustable, adjustable', direction info, light emitting, light dependent}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick, circuit ee IEC, set resistor graphic=var resistor IEC graphic]
  \draw [red] (0.0, 0.0) to [resistor={blue, Adjustable=blue, info'={$R$}}] (3.0, 0.0);
\end{tikzpicture}
% \tikz\path {[blue] (0,0) edge[line to] (1,1) };
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: (There are other ways to patch this, say by copying `adjustable` to another key/macro and then using that in a redefintion of `adjustable` …)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response.  I appreciate that you not only provided code that works but that you took the time to explain the answer.